# Getting only key value back from MongoMapper to_json result

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

Sorry for the newbie question but still very new to Ruby and Mongo.
Not 100% sure what I am missing, but how would I get just the value back
from "url" in the following json result?

```
[{"url":"www.google.com"}]
```

So I want something like if I do a

```
puts url_var
```

it should just display www.google.com

MongoMapper code to get URl from Mongo

```
redirect_url = Surl.all(:url_key => "#{urlkey}") 
myjson = redirect_url.to_json(:only => [:url])
puts redirect_url
```

gives me

```
[{"url":"www.google.com"}]
```

if I do something like

```
redirect_url.each do |key,value|
  puts key
  puts value
end
```

key is still the full json string and value is empty.

Surely I must be missing something really basic here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I assume `Surl` is a model of yours, which has at least these fields `url_key` and `url`, so to access the url you don't have to convert the result to json and then fetch to key, but you can access it directly.

`Surl.all` returns an array (check the mongo mapper docs), if you want a single result use `Surl.find_by_url_key(urlkey)`. Now you can access the url directly by using `puts redirect_url.url`

```
redirect_url = Surl.find_by_url_key(urlkey)
puts redirect_url.url # => "www.google.com"
```

Be sure to read up on http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/dynamic-querying.html and http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/querying.html, to understand the results and differences.

Comment: This is the error I get back : NoMethodError at /430f
undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Not really understanding the Surl.find_by_url_key. Where does
find_by_url_key come from?

Comment: aah ok I see find_by_url_key is a dynamic query

Comment: Got it thanks Iwe

I changed your

    redirect_url = Surl.find_by_url_key(:url_key => urlkey)

to

    redirect_url = Surl.find_by_url_key(urlkey)

and it works perfectly :)